# mvn deploy --> maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign failing. Has worked for a week now. No changes to POM beyond new project version number

Tags: java, maven, gnupg

I've had success with `mvn deploy` for about a week now, and suddenly it's not working. It used to prompt me for my passphrase (in a dialog window--I'm using Kleopatra on Windows 7, 32bit), but it's not any more. The only thing that's changed in the POM is the project's version number.

There are two random outcomes, both bad:

First, this output, which is printed *without me pressing any keys*:

```
R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava>mvn deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building XBN-Java 0.1.4.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:attach-artifact (attach-artifacts) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts) @ xbnjava ---

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "MY NAME HERE <MY_EMAIL_HERE@yahoo.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 4AB64866, created 2014-07-15

OK Your orders please
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
D 4204
OK
OK
OK
```

After pressing enter, this is the response:

```
gpg: Invalid passphrase; please try again ...
gpg: Invalid passphrase; please try again ...

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "MY NAME HERE <MY_EMAIL_HERE@yahoo.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 4AB64866, created 2014-07-15

OK Your orders please
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
D 5220
OK
gpg: AllowSetForegroundWindow(5220) failed: Access is denied.

OK
OK
OK
gpg: AllowSetForegroundWindow(5220) failed: Access is denied.
```

It freezes again here, at which point I cancel with Ctrl+C

```
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava>
```

I see the `AllowSetForegroundWindow(5220)`, and found [this about it](http://lists.wald.intevation.org/pipermail/gpg4win-users-en/2009-August/000354.html), but it doesn't say anything specific to do.

I tried it again and got this:

```
R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava>mvn deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building XBN-Java 0.1.4.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:attach-artifact (attach-artifacts) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts) @ xbnjava ---

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "MY NAME HERE <MY_EMAIL_HERE@yahoo.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 4AB64866, created 2014-07-15
```

I enter my passphrase here and press enter, but nothing happens. It's stuck. I cancel the process and it prints my passphrase in plain-text:

```
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? MY_PASSPHRASE_PRINTED_HERE
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava>
```

I try it *again* and the original stuff happens again ("...OK Your orders please OK OK OK OK OK..."). I enter my passphrase, and it starts working (I'm not sure when it actually took, it seems now), meaning the jars are uploaded successfully, but at the end of the log, after the "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" message...

```
R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava>mvn deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building XBN-Java 0.1.4.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:attach-artifact (attach-artifacts) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts) @ xbnjava ---

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "MY NAME HERE <MY_EMAIL_HERE@yahoo.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 4AB64866, created 2014-07-15


You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "MY NAME HERE <MY_EMAIL_HERE@yahoo.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 4AB64866, created 2014-07-15


You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "MY NAME HERE <MY_EMAIL_HERE@yahoo.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 4AB64866, created 2014-07-15


You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "MY NAME HERE <MY_EMAIL_HERE@yahoo.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 4AB64866, created 2014-07-15

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava\pom.xml to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.4.1\xbnjava-0.1.4.1.pom
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.4.1\download\xbnjava-0.1.4.1.jar to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.4.1\xbnjava-0.1.4.1.jar
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.4.1\download\xbnjava-0.1.4.1-javadoc.jar to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.4.1\xbnjava-0.1.4.1-javadoc.jar
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.4.1\download\xbnjava-0.1.4.1-sources.jar to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.4.1\xbnjava-0.1.4.1-sources.jar
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava\target\xbnjava-0.1.4.1.pom.asc to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.4.1\xbnjava-0.1.4.1.pom.asc
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava\target\gpg\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.4.1\download\xbnjava-0.1.4.1.jar.asc to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.4.1\xbnjava-0.1.4.1.jar.asc
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava\target\gpg\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.4.1\download\xbnjava-0.1.4.1-javadoc.jar.asc to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.4.1\xbnjava-0.1.4.1-javadoc.jar.asc
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava\target\gpg\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.4.1\download\xbnjava-0.1.4.1-sources.jar.asc to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.4.1\xbnjava-0.1.4.1-sources.jar.asc
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ xbnjava ---
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1.pom
         Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1.pom (6 KB at 4.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/maven-metadata.xml
            Downloaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/maven-metadata.xml (314 B at 0.9 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/maven-metadata.xml
            Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/maven-metadata.xml (314 B at 1.4 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1.jar
             Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1.jar (630 KB at 439.6 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1-javadoc.jar
               Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1-javadoc.jar (5093 KB at 572.4 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1-sources.jar
                 Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1-sources.jar (10728 KB at 609.9 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1.pom.asc
            Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1.pom.asc (499 B at 2.0 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1.jar.asc
            Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1.jar.asc (499 B at 1.9 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1-javadoc.jar.asc
            Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1-javadoc.jar.asc (499 B at 2.0 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1-sources.jar.asc
            Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1-sources.jar.asc (499 B at 2.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 37.724 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-30T13:58:42-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/17M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It ends with this:

```
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\applications\programming\python_341\Lib\cmd.py", line 45, in ?
    import string, sys
  File "C:\applications\programming\python_341\Lib\string.py", line 73
    class Template(metaclass=_TemplateMetaclass):
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Note that, with all those

```
You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "MY NAME HERE <MY_EMAIL_HERE@yahoo.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 4AB64866, created 2014-07-15
```

I never touch the keyboard.

---

Full settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
   <servers>
      <server>
         <id>ossrh</id>
         <username>MY_SONATYPE_DOT_COM_USERNAME</username>
         <password>MY_SONATYPE_DOT_COM_PASSWORD</password>
      </server>
   </servers>

   <pluginGroups></pluginGroups>
   <proxies></proxies>
   <mirrors></mirrors>
   <profiles></profiles>
</settings>
```

Full pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.github.aliteralmind</groupId>
   <artifactId>xbnjava</artifactId>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <version>0.1.4.1</version>
   <name>XBN-Java</name>
   <url>https://github.com/aliteralmind/xbnjava</url>
   <inceptionYear>2014</inceptionYear>
   <organization>
      <name>Jeff Epstein</name>
   </organization>
   <description>XBN-Java is a collection of generically-useful backend (server side, non-GUI) programming utilities, featuring RegexReplacer and FilteredLineIterator. XBN-Java is the foundation of Codelet (http://codelet.aliteralmind.com).</description>

   <licenses>
      <license>
         <name>Lesser General Public License (LGPL) version 3.0</name>
         <url>https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.txt</url>
      </license>
      <license>
         <name>Apache Software License (ASL) version 2.0</name>
         <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      </license>
   </licenses>

   <developers>
      <developer>
         <name>Jeff Epstein</name>
         <email>aliteralmind-github@yahoo.com</email>
         <roles>
            <role>Lead Developer</role>
         </roles>
      </developer>
   </developers>

   <issueManagement>
      <system>GitHub Issue Tracker</system>
      <url>https://github.com/aliteralmind/xbnjava/issues</url>
   </issueManagement>

   <distributionManagement>
     <snapshotRepository>
       <id>ossrh</id>
       <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
     </snapshotRepository>
     <repository>
       <id>ossrh</id>
       <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
     </repository>
   </distributionManagement>

   <scm>
      <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:aliteralmind/xbnjava.git</connection>
      <url>scm:git:git@github.com:aliteralmind/xbnjava.git</url>
      <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:aliteralmind/xbnjava.git</developerConnection>
   </scm>

   <properties>
      <java.version>1.7</java.version>
      <jarprefix>R:\jeffy\programming\build\/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/download/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</jarprefix>
   </properties>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <artifacts>
                        <artifact>
                           <file>${jarprefix}.jar</file>
                           <type>jar</type>
                        </artifact>
                        <artifact>
                           <file>${jarprefix}-javadoc.jar</file>
                           <type>jar</type>
                           <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
                        </artifact>
                        <artifact>
                           <file>${jarprefix}-sources.jar</file>
                           <type>jar</type>
                           <classifier>sources</classifier>
                        </artifact>
                     </artifacts>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                  <phase>verify</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>sign</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

      <!--
   <profiles>
      This profile will sign the JAR file, sources file, and javadocs file using the GPG key on the local machine.
      See: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/How+To+Generate+PGP+Signatures+With+Maven
      <profile>
         <id>release-sign-artifacts</id>
         <activation>
            <property>
               <name>release</name>
               <value>true</value>
            </property>
         </activation>
      </profile>
   </profiles>
      -->

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
         <version>4.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
         <version>2.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
         <version>3.3.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
         <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
         <version>16.0</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set your gpg.passphrase in your ~/.m2/settings.xml like so:

```
<server>
  <id>gpg.passphrase</id>
  <passphrase>clear or encrypted text</passphrase>
</server>
```

Or pass it as a parameter when calling maven:

```
mvn -Dgpg.passphrase=yourpassphrase deploy
```

Comment: And start the command with a space to prevent it from getting saved in history.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled gpg4win (of which Kleopatra is part), restarted my computer, and re-installed gpg4win, and the passphrase issue went away. The dialog popped up and prompted me for my password.

```
R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava>mvn  deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building XBN-Java 0.1.4.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:attach-artifact (attach-artifacts) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts) @ xbnjava ---

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "MY NAME HERE <MY_EMAIL_HERE@yahoo.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 4AB64866, created 2014-07-15


You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "MY NAME HERE <MY_EMAIL_HERE@yahoo.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 4AB64866, created 2014-07-15


You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "MY NAME HERE <MY_EMAIL_HERE@yahoo.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 4AB64866, created 2014-07-15


You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "MY NAME HERE <MY_EMAIL_HERE@yahoo.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 4AB64866, created 2014-07-15

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ xbnjava ---
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava\pom.xml to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.4.1\xbnjava-0.1.4.1.pom
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.4.1\download\xbnjava-0.1.4.1.jar to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.4.1\xbnjava-0.1.4.1.jar
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.4.1\download\xbnjava-0.1.4.1-javadoc.jar to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.4.1\xbnjava-0.1.4.1-javadoc.jar
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.4.1\download\xbnjava-0.1.4.1-sources.jar to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.4.1\xbnjava-0.1.4.1-sources.jar
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava\target\xbnjava-0.1.4.1.pom.asc to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.4.1\xbnjava-0.1.4.1.pom.asc
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava\target\gpg\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.4.1\download\xbnjava-0.1.4.1.jar.asc to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.4.1\xbnjava-0.1.4.1.jar.asc
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava\target\gpg\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.4.1\download\xbnjava-0.1.4.1-javadoc.jar.asc to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.4.1\xbnjava-0.1.4.1-javadoc.jar.asc
[INFO] Installing R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\z__for_git_commit_only\xbnjava\target\gpg\jeffy\programming\build\xbnjava-0.1.4.1\download\xbnjava-0.1.4.1-sources.jar.asc to C:\Users\jeffy\.m2\repository\com\github\aliteralmind\xbnjava\0.1.4.1\xbnjava-0.1.4.1-sources.jar.asc
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ xbnjava ---
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1.pom
         Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1.pom (6 KB at 0.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/maven-metadata.xml
            Downloaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/maven-metadata.xml (314 B at 1.2 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/maven-metadata.xml
            Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/maven-metadata.xml (314 B at 1.2 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1.jar
             Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1.jar (630 KB at 453.2 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1-javadoc.jar
               Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1-javadoc.jar (5093 KB at 605.6 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1-sources.jar
                 Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1-sources.jar (10728 KB at 609.6 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1.pom.asc
            Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1.pom.asc (499 B at 1.7 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1.jar.asc
            Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1.jar.asc (499 B at 1.6 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1-javadoc.jar.asc
            Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1-javadoc.jar.asc (499 B at 1.7 KB/sec)
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1-sources.jar.asc
            Uploaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/github/aliteralmind/xbnjava/0.1.4.1/xbnjava-0.1.4.1-sources.jar.asc (499 B at 2.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:18 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-30T14:30:23-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\applications\programming\python_341\Lib\cmd.py", line 45, in ?
    import string, sys
  File "C:\applications\programming\python_341\Lib\string.py", line 73
    class Template(metaclass=_TemplateMetaclass):
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

There's still the invalid syntax issue at the end of the log, which I'm about to post in a followup question.

Sorry. I hope this helps someone in the future. Or in the past. Whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Definily it will work:

### GPG version:

```
C:\Users\joao.almeida>gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.3
libgcrypt 1.8.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

---

### pom.xml

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <gpgArguments>
          <arg>--pinentry-mode</arg>
          <arg>loopback</arg>
        </gpgArguments>
        <keyname>example</keyname>
        <passphrase>************</passphrase>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>sign-artifacts</id>
          <phase>install</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>sign</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

---

or moving authentication to settings.xml.

### settings.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>RELEASE</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <gpg.keyname>example</gpg.keyname>
        <gpg.passphrase>************</gpg.passphrase>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

### pom.xml

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <gpgArguments>
          <arg>--pinentry-mode</arg>
          <arg>loopback</arg>
        </gpgArguments>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>sign-artifacts</id>
          <phase>install</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>sign</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

executing mvn install:

```
mvn -f C:\.dev\.wkp\4.7\huhula\mvn.sign\pom.xml -s C:\.m2\dev\settings.xml install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.ex:mvn.sign:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin is missing. @ line 9, column 12
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mvn.sign 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ mvn.sign ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ mvn.sign ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ mvn.sign ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mvn.sign ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ mvn.sign ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ mvn.sign ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ mvn.sign ---
[INFO] Installing C:\.dev\.wkp\4.7\huhula\mvn.sign\target\mvn.sign-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\.m2\dev\repository\org\ex\mvn.sign\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\mvn.sign-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\.dev\.wkp\4.7\huhula\mvn.sign\pom.xml to C:\.m2\dev\repository\org\ex\mvn.sign\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\mvn.sign-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.6:sign (sign-artifacts) @ mvn.sign ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.105 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-22T13:13:37-02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/159M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```